# Multiple GET Rest APIs on different fields of a table or One Rest API in DDD

Tags: rest, get, domain-driven-design

I wanted to provide functionality to clients from my service to get the data based on different fields or sometimes combination of fields. Eg.

```
getByA
getByB
getByC
getByAandB
getByAandC
```

In domain driven design, while designing the GET APIs, what should I do out of the following 2:

1. Should I create individual get api for all such functionalities I wanted to provide?
2. Should I create one get API with all the possible gets by using all these fields in query parameter. Eg.

> get?A=?&B=?&C=?

Which one is the better way to do this? Any suggestions on best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a middle path between using individual GET APIs for each of these queries and creating one GET API.

You could use the **Specification** pattern to expose one GET API, but translate it into a `Domain Specification Object` before passing it on to the Domain layer for querying. You typically do this transformation in your `View Controller`, before invoking the `Application Service`.

Martin Fowler and Eric Evans have published a great paper on using Specifications: https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf

As the paper states, *The central idea of Specification is to separate the statement of how to match a candidate, from the candidate object that it is matched against.*

Note:

- You are fine if you are using this pattern for the Query side as you have outlined in your question, and avoid reusing it in different contexts. For ex., DO NOT use a specification object on both the query side and command side, if you are using (or plan to use) CQRS. You will be creating a central dependency between two parts, that NEED to be kept separate.
- Specifications are handy when you want to represent a domain concept. Evaluate your queries (getByAandB and getByAandC) to draw out the question you are asking to the domain (For ex., ask your domain expert to describe the data he is trying to fetch).